# I don't see errors but still it doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was writing a script for deleting tiles as player moves.
But I seem to get an issue

> Warning    CS0618  'Object.FindObjectOfType()' is obsolete: 'Object.FindObjectOfType has been deprecated. Use Object.FindFirstObjectByType instead or if finding any instance is acceptable the faster Object.FindAnyObjectByType

and my script is running but not working.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    GroundSpawner groundSpawner;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        groundSpawner = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GroundSpawner>();
        // here "GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GroundSpawner>();" gets highlighted in green.
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        groundSpawner.SpawnTile();
        Destroy(gameObject, 2);
    }
}
```

and this is the other script which is being referred to in upper script.
It works fine.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject groundTile;
    Vector3 nextSpawnPoint;

    public void SpawnTile ()
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(groundTile,nextSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
        nextSpawnPoint = temp.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            SpawnTile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work"? The Warning has probably nothing to do with it.